# INVALID_ARGUMENT (400 error) when calling Stackdriver Error Reporting API

Tags: stackdriver, google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-error-reporting

When trying to invoke the [Stackdriver Error Reporting API](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/) ([via the API explorer](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.events/report) or via the [Client-Side JavaScript library](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/client-side-js)), I receive the following error:

Request:

```
{ "message" : "test" }
```

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

The Stackdriver Error Reporting API is enabled and I have Owner rights to the App Engine project.

Is the API simply not functional? If I'm doing something wrong, can someone try to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for reporting events says that a [ServiceContext is required](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.events/report#ReportedErrorEvent).

If you're only sending a message (not a stacktrace / exception) you'll need to include a [context with a reportLocation](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/ErrorContext#SourceLocation) as well. This is noted in the documentation of the `message` field, but it's not obvious.

The following works from the API explorer:

```
{
 "context": {
  "reportLocation": {
   "functionName": "My Function"
  }
 },
 "message": "error message",
 "serviceContext": {
  "service": "My Microservice",
 }
}
```

You might be interested in the docs on [How Error are Grouped](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/grouping) too.

FWIW, I work on this product and I think the error message is too generic. The problem is (?) that the serving stack scrubs the message unless they're annotated as being for public consumption. I'll chase that down.

Comment: Upon receiving a request, the API should validate that all required parameters are present. If they are absent, the API should throw an exception with the particular parameter(s) missing.

Comment: Note that [the JS implementation does not specify a reportLocation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/stackdriver-errors-js/blob/master/dist/stackdriver-errors-concat.js#L81). It was in testing the JS wrapper that I first encountered the 400 error and it appears that that's why.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Keep in mind that module is marked as 'Experimental'